# how to get value of the text box in dynamic table data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table that has a text input box. I want to get the value of the text box value within the tr element.how do I do it?

```
$(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function(){

    $('#employee_table tr').each(function(row, tr){

      var asd = $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text();//get the value
      var asd01 = $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text();//not get the value of the text box
        alert(asd);
  });    

  });
```

above code with getting all the static content of table row.how do I get the text value into the variable within table data?[image]

Comment: It may possible, you are looking for `td` value in fourth column, but there is a textbox, so after finding `td`, get the textbox and then apply `text()` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.find('input')` since you have just one input in your `tr` and `.val()` to get the value.

```
let your_array = [];

$(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function() {

  $('#employee_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {

    your_array.push({
      emp_id: $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
      input_val: $(tr).find('input').val()
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: first time get the undefined next get the correct value .because table header also identify as tr how do ignore first tr value

Comment: use `$('#employee_table tbody tr')` so that it takes only within `tbody`

Comment: done bro. simple i thought get emp_id,hour store in 2d array .how push array in to this above to value?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: if you are looking for the first col, use `$(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();`

Comment: yes bro i want to push valueof  var asd = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(); and
  var asd01 = $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').find('input').val(); in to the array and by using php i want store in mysql database.what is best way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200688/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-nipun258).

Answer (score 2):

For 4 td contain input not a text element .so need to find `input` value instead of text

```
    $(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function(){
        $('#employee_table tr').each(function(row, tr){
          var asd = $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text();//get the value
          var asd01 = $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').find('input').val();// value of input box
            alert(asd);
      });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function(){

    $('#employee_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr){
      console.log("Get Html "+$(this).find("td:eq(4)").html());
     console.log("Get Text box value"+$(this).closest().find("input[type='text']").val());
  });    

  });
```